# Why my youtube video made with ffmpeg only shows 360P and 1080P on mobile devices but works fine on desktop?

Tags: encoding, ffmpeg, youtube

I am trying to create a video from an image and sound file with ffmpeg.

This is what I use:

```
ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -r 6  -i current_image.png -i current_audio.wav -shortest -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -tune stillimage -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac out.mp4
```

But uploading this on youtube will display only in 360P and 1080P on mobile devices while on Desktop I have all the resolutions up to 1080P.

It has the same effect with the command from FFmpeg [wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/YouTube) on enconding from youtube

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 2 -i input.png -i audio.m4a -c:v libx264 -preset medium -tune stillimage -crf 18 -c:a copy -shortest -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mkv
```

I have no idea why is this happening, I could use some guidance.